# What will happen when ActionMapper return "null"?

Tags: struts2

I am fresher in Struts2, I've read request flow of struts from site https://struts.apache.org/docs/the-struts-2-request-flow.html

My question is what will happen when `ActionMapper` returns "null"?

Comment: Where did you read from the link that *ActionMapper return "null"*? Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Per https://struts.apache.org/docs/actionmapper.html, "When given an HttpServletRequest, the ActionMapper may return null if no action invocation request matches..."  And I believe that in this case an exception is thrown.

Comment: It depends on the code which creates `ActionMapper`. In general next filter will be called. Static resource will be served. I suggest you to look at the source code.